# Flutter: Responsive design with a fixed height

Tags: dart, flutter

I am creating a section where to administer the club.

The problem that I have is related to the design.

I try to indicate that it has the same vertical height on the horizontal side, but I still do not understand why the bots are not adapted according to their size ratio.

I have been thinking about how to do it for more than 4 hours and I have not been able to do it, I hope someone can help me.

**My goal**: That the design of the vertical side be the same as the horizontal

**Here I show you my code**

```
return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("LINE UP"),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue[500],
      ),
      body: LayoutBuilder(
          builder: (context, constraints) {
            return new Container(
                color: Colors.blue[800],
                child: new Stack(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      new Positioned.fill(
                          child: new SingleChildScrollView(
                              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                              child: new Column(
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    new Container(
                                        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                                          image: new DecorationImage(
                                              image: new AssetImage(imgStadium),
                                              fit: BoxFit.fitWidth
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        height: 411.4,
                                        width: constraints.maxWidth,
                                        child: new Stack(
                                          children: <Widget>[
                                            // BOT1
                                            Positioned(
                                                top: 120.0,
                                                left: 168.0,
                                                child: new GestureDetector(
                                                  child: new Column(
                                                    children: <Widget>[
                                                      new Container(
                                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                          image: new DecorationImage(
                                                            image: new AssetImage(
                                                                imgPlayer1),
                                                            fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                                          ),
                                                        ),
                                                        height: 40.0,
                                                        width: 30.0,
                                                      ),
                                                      new Container(
                                                        width: 70.0,
                                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                          shape: BoxShape
                                                              .rectangle,
                                                          color: Colors.black
                                                              .withOpacity(0.5),
                                                        ),
                                                        child: new Text(
                                                          "${textPlayer1}",
                                                          style: new TextStyle(
                                                              color: Colors
                                                                  .white,
                                                              fontWeight: FontWeight
                                                                  .bold,
                                                              fontSize: 12.0),
                                                          textAlign: TextAlign
                                                              .center,),
                                                      )
                                                    ],
                                                  ),
                                                  onTap: () {
                                                    setState(() {
                                                      _showModalSheet(1);
                                                    });
                                                  },
                                                )
                                            ),
                                            //BOT2
                                            Positioned(
                                                top: topPositionPlayer2,
                                                left: leftPositionPlayer2,
                                                child: new GestureDetector(
                                                  child: new Column(
                                                    children: <Widget>[
                                                      new Container(
                                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                          image: new DecorationImage(
                                                            image: new AssetImage(
                                                                imgPlayer2),
                                                            fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                                          ),
                                                        ),
                                                        height: 40.0,
                                                        width: 30.0,
                                                      ),
                                                      new Container(
                                                        width: 70.0,
                                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                          shape: BoxShape
                                                              .rectangle,
                                                          color: Colors.black
                                                              .withOpacity(0.5),
                                                        ),
                                                        child: new Text(
                                                          "${textPlayer2}",
                                                          style: new TextStyle(
                                                              color: Colors
                                                                  .white,
                                                              fontWeight: FontWeight
                                                                  .bold,
                                                              fontSize: 12.0),
                                                          textAlign: TextAlign
                                                              .center,),
                                                      )
                                                    ],
                                                  ),
                                                  onTap: () {
                                                    setState(() {
                                                      _showModalSheet(2);
                                                    });
                                                  },
                                                )
                                            ),
                                            //BOT3
                                            Positioned(
                                                top: topPositionPlayer3,
                                                left: leftPositionPlayer3,
                                                child: new GestureDetector(
                                                  child: new Column(
                                                    children: <Widget>[
                                                      new Container(
                                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                          image: new DecorationImage(
                                                            image: new AssetImage(
                                                                imgPlayer3),
                                                            fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                                          ),
                                                        ),
                                                        height: 40.0,
                                                        width: 30.0,
                                                      ),
                                                      new Container(
                                                        width: 70.0,
                                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                          shape: BoxShape
                                                              .rectangle,
                                                          color: Colors.black
                                                              .withOpacity(0.5),
                                                        ),
                                                        child: new Text(
                                                          "${textPlayer3}",
                                                          style: new TextStyle(
                                                              color: Colors
                                                                  .white,
                                                              fontWeight: FontWeight
                                                                  .bold,
                                                              fontSize: 12.0),
                                                          textAlign: TextAlign
                                                              .center,),
                                                      )
                                                    ],
                                                  ),
                                                  onTap: () {
                                                    setState(() {
                                                      _showModalSheet(3);
                                                    });
                                                  },
                                                )
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        )
                                    )
                                  ]
                              )
                          )
                      )
                    ]
                )
            );
          }
      )
    );
```

**Here I show you some screenshots.**

**Vertical mode** - Perfect.
[image]

**Horizontal mode** - I move it and the background image does not adapt.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are providing all height and width related to vertical mode so their is problem in horizontal view.
I think that you have to try MediaQuery.of(context).size.width and get width And set whatever ratio you want to set for padding or to get player image to center so it works for both horizontal and vertical to.

Comment: I have managed to adapt following your steps, thank you very much !!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Generally, at the moment you're indenting halfway across the screen, I would refactor that to a separate method, or even a separate Widget class.